# checking if two arraylist objects matches

Tags: java

how do I check if an object of an arraylist matches with another  one no matter the order of the elements and their number of occurrences. let's say I have:

```
obj1   contains    "boy",  "girl",  "kid"
obj2   contains     "girl",   "kid",  "boy", "girl"
obj3   contains     "woman",  "boy",  "girl",   "kid"
```

all of arraylist

I want the program to achieve this:

```
obj1    =     obj2   true
obj1    =     obj3   false
obj2    =     obj3   false
```

Comment: And what you have tried till now??

Comment: Sounds more like a `Set` than a `List`.

Comment: refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386278/how-to-check-if-objects-in-an-array-list-has-the-same-value

Comment: Convert both lists to Sets, find the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of the sets and check if it has the same size as the original sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you mean the following. You want to check whether unique elements contained in your lists are the same. The order does not matter.

To solve this problem you need set that contain only unique elements and do not preserve order:

```
List<String> first = ....
List<String> second = ....

boolean result = new HashSet<>(first).equals(new HashSet<>(second));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `containsAll()` method:

```
    List a = Arrays.asList("boy", "girl", "kid");
    List b = Arrays.asList("girl", "kid", "boy", "girl");
    List c = Arrays.asList("woman", "boy", "girl", "kid");

    System.out.println(a.containsAll(b));     // true
    System.out.println(a.containsAll(c));     // false
    System.out.println(b.containsAll(c));     // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, read about List .contains method. Use it in nested loops with boolean flag to indicate whether one list item satisfies .equals to any item in other list.

You will also need to decide whether comparison should be two way. You may have a scenario where all items of obj1 are present in obj2, but all items of obj2 are not present in obj1. In other words, obj2 is a superset of obj1.